# Unable to install aurelia-fetch-client with the aurelia-cli

Tags: aurelia

When I try to install the aurelia-fetch-client I get this error:

[image]

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: What version of the cli are you running? `au -v`

Comment: Yeah, you need to upgrade your CLI. `npm install aurelia-cli@latest -g`